# Scala Spring @Value in constructor body

Tags: spring, scala

I have the following spring pseudo-code wired scala class.

```
@Service
class Something {

@Value("${some.property}")
val someString : String

// do something with someString in the body
}
```

However this won't work because the someString is part of the constructor body, and spring can't wire in the values until after the constructor has executed.

How can I wire in @Value's so that it works, and isn't horrible (my current solution with a custom constructor containing all the values I need just doesn't feel "scala" and looks horrible.

Edit: To clarify, my current solution is this:

```
@Service
class Something { 
  @Autowired 
  def this(@Value("${some.prop}") prop : String) { 
    this() 
    // do other construction stuff here
  }
}
```

I just think it looks ugly and feel there is a better way. I also don't like having to create these secondary constructors when I'd rather enforce it on the primary constructor.

Edit 2: To further clarify, I was hoping there was a way to do something like this:

```
@Service
class Something(@Value("${some.property}") string : String) {
// use the value in your constructor here
}
```

Because this looks far more elegant. I just can't get it to work :)

Comment: I think you need to add a @BeanProperty annotation to val someString. See http://www.infoq.com/articles/scala_and_spring

Comment: If I set @BeanProperty then that will make a java-style getter and setter. That's not what I want. What I want is spring to inject the value as part of the "construction" process. Ie, I'm looking for the best-scala-ish way to do this:

Comment: public class Something { 
@Autowired
public Something(@Value("{some.property}") String someString) {}
}

Comment: something like this may work (sorry typing from memory, can't test here) `class Something @Autowired() (@(Value("{some.property}") @field) var prop: String)`. Key points are that you have to use the () after the annotation to annotate a constructor and that you have to specify that you're annotating a field.

Comment: @monkjack: How is Spring supposed to "inject the value as part of the construction process" when your class is abstract (in the first version)? It would require to somehow materialize a concrete class at runtime all by itself, and implement someString  to return the right value. Not exactly impossible, but I guess you're asking too much... You current solution looks sensible to me, I would not expect anything better. Except maybe by toying with a compiler plugin or scala macros.

Comment: I clearly put in the original question "this doesn't work". I know the class doesn't compile, it's a psuedo-code ish "example" of what I wanted to achieve :)

Comment: I know, but that's not what I mean. You also explicitly said that your solution with a "custom constructor containing all the values I need" is what you want to avoid.  Problem is, if you don't have this constructor, and given that `someString ` is a val and not a var, the only way to set it is by defining a subclass of `Something` and implement/override `someString`. Which would require Spring to construct a class at runtime.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, after all the back and forth, I *think* I understand better what you want, so here's my take on it:

```
import scala.annotation.BeanProperty
import scala.annotation.target.beanSetter
class Something @Autowired() (@(Value @beanSetter)("{some.property}") @BeanProperty var prop: String)
```

This is essentially Paolo Falabella's solution, except that I try to avoid having Spring acces private fields. To this end I let scala autogenerate a public java-like setter using `@BeanProperty` **and** apply `@Value` on it.
You can also improve the syntax somewhat by using a type alias:

```
type Value = org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value @beanSetter @beanGetter
class Something @Autowired() ( @BeanProperty@Value("{some.property}") var prop: String)
```

Comment: In my case I needed a $... @(Value @beanSetter)("${google.key.location}") @BeanProperty var keyLocation: String,

Answer (score 3):

You need to initialize `someString` to a value so that a real field is generated in the class.  Alternatively you can use a `var` instead of a `val`, but either way you'll have to initialize it.

For example:

```
@Service
class TestService {
  @Value("${testService.foo:bar}")
  val foo: String = null
  //var foo: String = _
}
```

[Decompiling](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui) TestService.class file you'll see that it put the annotation on a `private final String` field (you can also use [jclasslib bytecode viewer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jclasslib/)):

```
@Service
@ScalaSignature(bytes="\006\001!3A!\001\002\001\023\tYA+Z:u'\026\024h/[2f\025\t\031A!\001\005tKJ4\030nY3t\025\t)a!A\002osbT\021aB\001\004G>l7\001A\n\004\001)\021\002CA\006\021\033\005a!BA\007\017\003\021a\027M\\4\013\003=\tAA[1wC&\021\021\003\004\002\007\037\nTWm\031;\021\005M1R\"\001\013\013\003U\tQa]2bY\006L!a\006\013\003\027M\033\027\r\\1PE*,7\r\036\005\0063\001!\tAG\001\007y%t\027\016\036 \025\003m\001\"\001\b\001\016\003\tAqA\b\001C\002\023\005q$A\002g_>,\022\001\t\t\003C\021r!a\005\022\n\005\r\"\022A\002)sK\022,g-\003\002&M\t11\013\036:j]\036T!a\t\013\t\r!\002\001\025!\003!\003\0211wn\034\021)\t\035R\003(\017\t\003WYj\021\001\f\006\003[9\n!\"\0318o_R\fG/[8o\025\ty\003'A\004gC\016$xN]=\013\005E\022\024!\0022fC:\034(BA\0325\003=\031\bO]5oO\032\024\030-\\3x_J\\'\"A\033\002\007=\024x-\003\0028Y\t)a+\0317vK\006)a/\0317vK\006\n!(\001\f%wR,7\017^*feZL7-\032\030g_>T$-\031:~\021\025a\004\001\"\001>\003)Ig.\033;jC2L'0\032\013\002}A\0211cP\005\003\001R\021A!\0268ji\"\022\001A\021\t\003\007\032k\021\001\022\006\003\013J\n!b\035;fe\026|G/\0379f\023\t9EIA\004TKJ4\030nY3")
public class TestService
  implements ScalaObject
{

  @Value("${testService.foo:bar}")
  private final String foo;

  public String foo()
  {
    return this.foo;
  }

  public TestService()
  {
    null; this.foo = null;
  }
}
```

I use `@Value` on class members all the time, it's very convenient.

Comment: So basically you are advising to bypass the immutable nature of vals by having Spring directly write to the underlying private field? Not that is necessarily always evil (no need for dogmas in programming) but IMHO it does not go in the "more scalaish" direction that monkjack is aiming at. Using a var as you suggest is certainly saner (but not what monkjack wanted if I understand correctly)

Comment: It is a `val` that is being initialized at runtime.  Sort of like `val foo = someSpringMethod("${testService.foo:bar}")`.  After the class is instantiated and initialized by Spring the val cannot be changed by regular code.  So you get the benefit of having a `val`.   It does look wierd to have that `= null` when it really going to be initialized to another value, I agree.  But otherwise using a `var` you are at the mercy of other code mutating the value after initialization.

Comment: Totally true. I just wanted to stress what actually happened here. It's OK to bypass safety from time to time as long as you are fully aware of what it involves.

Comment: The fact I had a val to start with was just a typo in my "psuedo code" example. What I want is to have the constructor code in the body of the class, like is typical for scala, but at the same time I want to have autowired properties. Basically, I'm looking for a way to have constructor injection in scala without having secondary constructors. I think Paolo Falabella has the best suggestion so far (in a comment on my original post).

Comment: Ah, OK. unfortunate typo then, you might want to update your question.